# PHP SQL UPDATE Query issue

Tags: php, sql

I'm having trouble with this update query.INSERT works absolutely fine.My INSERT query and UPDATE query as follows,

This is the error that i've been getting.

```
db_exec:DB Error: 
 (UPDATE vms2 set invoiceid='', slicenseinfo='testVM',  
   manufacturerid='692', hyp='6', stitle='UBER', vmg='UBER', sversion='1716',  sinfo='', 
   purchdate='1367712000', licqty='7', lictype='192', dns='', ipv4='10.2.36.3', ipv4dns='102.32.3.55', 
    remip='110.2.3.3', remipdns='100.32.3.32', ipv6='', 
    hdd='', ram='', cores='',  WHERE id=14): 
    near "WHERE": syntax error


Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\test\php\editvm.php
            [line] => 149
            [function] => db_exec
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => PDO Object
                        (
                        )

                    [1] => UPDATE vms2 set invoiceid='', slicenseinfo='testVM',  manufacturerid='692', hyp='6', stitle='UBER', vmg='UBER', sversion='1716',  sinfo='', purchdate='1367712000', licqty='7', lictype='192', dns='', ipv4='10.2.36.3', ipv4dns='102.32.3.55', remip='110.2.3.3', remipdns='100.32.3.32', ipv6='', hdd='', ram='', cores='',  WHERE id=14
                )

        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [file] => C:\xampp\htdocs\test\index.php
            [line] => 490
            [args] => Array
                (
                    [0] => C:\xampp\htdocs\test\php\editvm.php
                )

            [function] => require
        )

)
```

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: You should not have `,` after the last value. But without seeing the code that generates the query, further help is impossible

Comment: Thanks Darhazer it was the comma..cheers

Answer (score 1):

Remove the last comma before the `WHERE`

Answer (score 0):

You have an extra comma before the Where clause which is not required

```
UPDATE vms2 set invoiceid='', slicenseinfo='testVM',  manufacturerid='692', hyp='6', stitle='UBER', vmg='UBER', sversion='1716',  sinfo='', purchdate='1367712000', licqty='7', lictype='192', dns='', ipv4='10.2.36.3', ipv4dns='102.32.3.55', remip='110.2.3.3', remipdns='100.32.3.32', ipv6='', hdd='', ram='', cores=''  WHERE id=14
```

This should work.

Answer (score 0):

Update the `UPDATE` command to this

```
 UPDATE vms2 set invoiceid='', slicenseinfo='testVM',  manufacturerid='692', hyp='6', stitle='UBER', vmg='UBER', sversion='1716',  sinfo='', purchdate='1367712000', licqty='7', lictype='192', dns='', ipv4='10.2.36.3', ipv4dns='102.32.3.55', remip='110.2.3.3', remipdns='100.32.3.32', ipv6='', hdd='', ram='', cores=''  WHERE id=14`
```

Comment: it was the comma before "cores" .thnaks for your help